# How can i extend my git log command to get desired output

Tags: git, git-log

how can I extend the following command so that the following desired output appears?

```
git log --pretty=oneline --no-abbrev-commit
```

Output:

```
fcdb58d185039bd732e877a3cae6485608a39e70 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merge pull > request #42413 from bioothod:export_golang_functions_ma ster
1cc66e060d7ec25c89807065d453f20ab46ca93e Temporarily disable xla_compiler_test.
41f429e7b5e8393f3cddd6f2b53b148d19874d44 [XLA:SPMD] Fix bug in partial replicate resharding.
```

desired Output:

```
 tag_version,commit-id, commit-message, author_email
```

Comment: You can get somewhat close to what you want using `--format`, but there may not be a Git tag on the given commit, and there's no way to format those precisely when they exist. Separately: Don't use  the[tag:linux] tag. (Inspect its tag information to see why, e.g., hover your mouse over the tag in your question.)

Comment: Hello, nearly the solution: git log --pretty=format:"%H;%ae;%s"

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following command:

```
git log --no-walk --tags --pretty='format:%H, %s, %ae' --decorate=full
```

%H will show the full commit hash, %s for commit-message, and %ae for author email,
"--no-walk --tags" will show every single commit which has a tag attached to it.

You can read about this more [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats).